# How to access a secret group's posts using facebook-api?

Tags: facebook, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I am a part of a secret group. I want to get all of the posts and their metadata. I use the following code:

```
import facebook

if __name__ == '__main__':

    APP_SECRET = ""
    APP_ID = ""
    PAGE_ID = "" ## Page ID of the secret group
    access_token = facebook.get_app_access_token(APP_ID, APP_SECRET)

    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
    resp = graph.get_object('me/accounts')
    page_access_token = None
    for page in resp['data']:
        if page['id'] == PAGE_ID:
            page_access_token = page['access_token']
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(page_access_token)
```

but I get this error:

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

on line `resp = graph.get_object('me/accounts')`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that you did not authorize the user. How to do that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

`/me/accounts` is the endpoint to get access to pages, for groups you need the `user_managed_groups` permission and the `/me/groups` endpoint. You need to use an active User Token for that, of course.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/groups

Comment: `resp = graph.get_object('me/groups')` is still giving me the same error. Form where do I get the `user_managed_groups` permission. Is it some ind of a token?

Comment: it´s a permission. you need to start reading the docs from the very beginning as it seems, i´ve included a link to the login part.